# Loop through all links and find the href

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is only finding the first link. Why is it not looping through all of the links?

http://jsfiddle.net/infatti/7r4fV/

```
var alertHref = $('#myLinks').find('a').attr('href');

$('#myDivs').find(alertHref).css('background-color', 'yellow');

<span id="myLinks">
  <a href="#div1">link 1</a>
  <a href="#div2">link 2</a>
</span>
<hr />
<div id="myDivs">
  <div id="div1">div 1</div>
  <div id="div2">div 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Because you didn't write a loop.

Comment: A dirty way: http://jsfiddle.net/K9m96/1/

Comment: Apparently Ian and I were working on similar answers using `map` - it looks like his comment beat my edit.

Answer (score 2):

`find('a')` returns a list of all the `a` elements, but `.attr('href')` returns the href of the first link only.

You need to loop through the `a` elements:

http://jsfiddle.net/Gj2R9/

```
$('#myLinks a').each(function() {
    $($(this).attr('href')).css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the clarification between find and attr.

Answer (score 1):

use `jQuery.each` to loop through more than one.

Using your [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/7r4fV/2/):

```
var $hrefs  = $('#myLinks').find('a[href]');
var $myDivs = $('#myDivs');

$hrefs.each(function(index,link){
   $(link.hash,$myDivs).css('background-color','yellow');
});
```

---

You could also use [map](http://api.jquery.com/map/) ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vol7ron/7r4fV/3/)):

```
var hrefs  = $('#myLinks').find('a[href]')
                          .map(function(){ return this.hash; })
                          .get();

$('#myDivs').find(hrefs.join(',')).css('background-color','yellow');
```